# Sharedpreferences data not saving when passing an intent string... activity crashing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities. In activity A when pressing a button sends you to activity B, in B it asks for input and returns that input to A where it is saved via SharedPreferences.When i try to save that value using SharedPreferences my app crashes. I cant figure out whats wrong. Here is activity A code which should save and display the value passed from activity B.

p.s.
using intents to pass the value back to A from B there is no problem, its just saving that value that is causing the issue.

```
TextView teamScore1;
SharedPreferences Score01;
public static String strTScore01 = "MySHaredString";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

           Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore01, 0);
    String dataReturned01 = Score01.getString("sharedString",
            "Cant LOAD data");
    teamScore1.setText(dataReturned01);
            initialize();
    intents();

}
private void initialize()....
private void intents() {
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("teamScore1")) {

        Intent i = getIntent();
        stringData1 = i.getStringExtra("teamScore1");


        // SCORE VALUES
        if (stringData1.length()> 0) {
            //calculations and data manipulation 
            intTScore_1 = Integer.parseInt(stringData1);
            total = intTScore_1 + total; // add to current total
            stringData1 = Integer.toString(total);


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Score01.edit();
            editor.putString("sharedString", stringData1);
            editor.commit();
            Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore01, 0);
            String dataReturned1 = Score01.getString("sharedString",
                    "Cant LOAD data");
            teamScore1.setText(dataReturned1);
```

logcat.....

```
11-07 19:36:01.712: D/AndroidRuntime(905): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

11-07 19:36:01.712: D/AndroidRuntime(905): CheckJNI is ON

11-07 19:36:01.832: D/AndroidRuntime(905): --- registering native functions ---

11-07 19:36:02.342: D/AndroidRuntime(905): Shutting down VM

11-07 19:36:02.342: D/dalvikvm(905): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

11-07 19:36:02.372: I/dalvikvm(905): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)

11-07 19:36:02.372: I/AndroidRuntime(905): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

11-07 19:36:02.732: D/AndroidRuntime(913): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

11-07 19:36:02.732: D/AndroidRuntime(913): CheckJNI is ON

11-07 19:36:02.852: D/AndroidRuntime(913): --- registering native functions ---

11-07 19:36:03.343: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter uid=10039

11-07 19:36:03.343: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 898 SIG: 9

11-07 19:36:03.363: I/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.thenewboston.travis while already resumed in com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter

11-07 19:36:03.363: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity }

11-07 19:36:03.373: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{45067ea0 com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter.NewGame paused=false}

11-07 19:36:03.447: D/AndroidRuntime(913): Shutting down VM

11-07 19:36:03.454: D/jdwp(913): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select

11-07 19:36:03.454: D/dalvikvm(913): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

11-07 19:36:03.505: I/AndroidRuntime(913): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

11-07 19:36:03.603: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter for activity 
com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity: pid=920 uid=10039 gids={}

11-07 19:36:03.663: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 898 uid 10039

11-07 19:36:03.873: W/ActivityThread(920): Application com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

11-07 19:36:03.913: I/System.out(920): Sending WAIT chunk

11-07 19:36:03.923: I/dalvikvm(920): Debugger is active

11-07 19:36:03.953: I/System.out(920): Debugger has connected

11-07 19:36:03.953: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:04.193: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:04.393: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:04.646: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:04.843: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:05.057: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:05.253: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:05.513: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:05.746: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:05.950: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:06.154: I/System.out(920): waiting for debugger to settle...

11-07 19:36:06.358: I/System.out(920): debugger has settled (1438)

11-07 19:36:07.377: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.MainActivity: 3784 ms 
(total 33895 ms)

11-07 19:36:09.143: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.petermihaylov.android.NEWGAME cmp=com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.NewGame (has extras) }

11-07 19:36:10.014: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.NewGame: 761 ms (total 761 ms)

11-07 19:36:14.062: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.petermihaylov.android.GAME cmp=com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.Game (has extras) }

11-07 19:36:24.117: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

11-07 19:36:24.186: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45062c78 com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.Game}

11-07 19:36:29.451: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4505ae90 com.petermihaylov.android.cardcounter/.NewGame}
```

After several long hours of try and catch statements narrowing down the problem I think i have solved it. Here is the code I hope it helps someone

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        initialize();
        intents();

        Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore1, 0);
        String dataReturned1 = Score01.getString("sharedString",
                "Cant LOAD data");
        teamScore1.setText(dataReturned1);
    }

    private void initialize() {...

    private void intents() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("teamScore1")) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            stringData1 = i.getStringExtra("teamScore1");
            Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore1, 0);

            if (stringData1.length() > 0) {


                intTScore_1 = Integer.parseInt(stringData1);
                total = intTScore_1 + total; // add to current total
                stringData1 = Integer.toString(total);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Score01.edit();
                editor.putString("sharedString", stringData1);
                editor.commit();

            }
```

Comment: you had better paste the logcat here, so we can specify your problem.

Comment: I guess that when the first time you start A, the intent doesn't contain any Extras, so stringData1 is null. This is your problem.

Comment: I am getting the same error even if I remove the sharedpreferences code in the onCreate method... so even if I have data in the StringData1 the app crashes

Comment: when pasting error logs, try to include only the part where the app started crashing - it starts in FATAL EXCEPTION: main and is followed by a stack trace

Comment: also, can you elaborate more on how data from activity B is returned to A? did you re-launch A? setResult?

Comment: A little new... trying to figure out where the fatal exception is located.... 
and Intent i = getIntent();
   stringData1 = i.getStringExtra("teamScore1"); 
this will return the data from activity B to activity A. I can use teamScore1.setText(stringData1); to set the data to the textview(teamScore1) and it works fine so data is passed back to activity A w/o any errors

Comment: I added try and catch (Exception e) {
     String error = e.toString();
     teamScore1.setText(error);
    }
which resulted in this error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        initialize();
        intents();

        Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore1, 0);
        String dataReturned1 = Score01.getString("sharedString",
                "Cant LOAD data");
        teamScore1.setText(dataReturned1);
    }

    private void initialize() {...

    private void intents() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("teamScore1")) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            stringData1 = i.getStringExtra("teamScore1");
            Score01 = getSharedPreferences(strTScore1, 0);

            if (stringData1.length() > 0) {


                intTScore_1 = Integer.parseInt(stringData1);
                total = intTScore_1 + total; // add to current total
                stringData1 = Integer.toString(total);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Score01.edit();
                editor.putString("sharedString", stringData1);
                editor.commit();

            }
```